# use of Undefined constant http_x_forwarded_for

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR))
{
    $pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}
else
{
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
use of undefined constant http_x_forwarded_for-assumed http_x_forwarded_for
```

i am not getting whats the actual problem. Help me out

Comment: i am getting the visitor's IP address its running fine on localhost but getting problem on web

Comment: This is a dupe of **every question on the Related sidebar** that mentions "undefined constant ... assumed" in the title.  Please, *please* perform due diligence next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing constants to [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php), which actually requires a string.

Change to:

```
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
```

The reason it works with the constants is because PHP fails to find the constant, it then issues the warnings you're seeing, and then falls back using the constant names as a string.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):

> string getenv ( string $varname )

Answer (score 2):

Put it in single quotes

```
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote the argument to `getenv`

`getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');`

Otherwise php thinks you are passing a constant.

https://www.php.net/getenv

`string getenv ( string $varname )` expects a string.

Unless you define `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` to a string previously, which I don't think is what you intended.

Comment: ok shall i change to getenv(REMOTE_ADDR) also as getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

Comment: @cnik2125 yep, all the calls to `getenv` basically